# Use HSTS response header in Azure Function app

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, hsts

I need to send HSTS header in the response header of Azure function app for API (not web app). I was able to add HSTS with required options, but unable to use `useHSTS` as below.

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
   ....
   builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
            {
                options.Preload = true;
                options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
            });
   ....
}
```

`Startup.cs` file is not allowing me to use `Configure` method with parameters as `IApplicationBuilder`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
 
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
 
            }

      }
```

Any suggestions to get HSTS header in the response is appreciated!

Comment: Which .net version you are using ?

Comment: It is .NET Core 3.1 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings

in host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    ...
    },
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": "api",
            "hsts": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "includeSubDomains": true,
                "maxAge": "365"
            },
            "customHeaders": {
                "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
                "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
                "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block"
            }
        }
    }
}
```